# Does SharePoint Foundation 2010 limit the number of users somehow?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am evaluating SharePoint Foundation 2010 (free edition) for a prospect with 50 users. Does Foundation 2010 limit the number of users somehow? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't; SharePoint Foundation is Free to use. Only the SharePoint Server (Standard & Enterprise) uses the Client Access License (CAL) model which is limited by CAL licenses per user.

Comment: SharePoint limit the number of users to 2 million per site collection (or that's what is supported) [SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

Comment: Yeah actually it is a maximum of 5 million total simultaneous user for the entire farm. It can hold more but I think thats when you hit a performance peak.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, this CAL model does not technically limit your usage of SP. But, for legal purposes you must ensure you have the right amount of CAL for your scenario.